# SwiftUI: Have the nth view from an array swapped out when the currentIndex value changes?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

There is an array of `Views`, and whenever the `currentPosition` variable changes, the view must change. However it is not changing.

I have a global `ObservableObject` class that has an array of `View`s, and a `currentPosition` value. My goal is to have the view changed according to the `currentPosition` variable.

```
class AXGlobalValues: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tabs: [AXTabItem] = [
        .init(webView: AXWebView()),
        .init(webView: AXWebView())
    ]
    
    @Published var currentPosition: Int = 0
}
```

On the SwiftUI view, I wrote `global.tabs[global.currentPosition].webView`, and I was expecting the webView to change based on the `global.currentPosition` value. However it didn't change.

What I tried to do was add an `onChange(of:)`, but since SwiftUI is a declarative language, I couldn't update the view.

```
struct AXTabView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var global: AXGlobalValues

    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(global.currentPosition)")
        
        global.tabs[global.currentPosition].webView
            .onChange(of: global.currentPosition) { newValue in
                // Not allowed in SwiftUI :(
                global.tabs[global.currentPosition].webView
            }
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can update the view based on the `currentPosition` variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have updated it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObservableObject` is part of the Combine framework and is designed to persist (or sync) a data model, it's not the right place to store SwiftUI View structs.

Also, for view data like `currentPosition` we usually use `@State var` with simple values or a custom struct when we want to group some related vars or have extra logic. `body` is recomputed when the `@State` changes.